# What is meant by "the erasure of the static type of the expression on which it is called" in the getClass() docs?

Tags: java

The documentation for the ["public final Class<?> getClass()"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method of Object says:

> The actual result type is Class<? extends |X|> where |X| is the
>   erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is
>   called. For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:

I don't understand the explanation, particularly with regard to what |X| is said to be - "the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called".

What form of notation is |X| ? Or maybe, where else would  |X| type notation be used?

Comment: The notation `|X|` was used as _meta-variable_, placeholder, outside of the java syntax. In Math on would maybe use a greek letter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Java Language Specification [mandates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2) that this method is treated in a special way by the compiler:

> The method `getClass` returns the `Class` object that represents the class of the object.
>
> A `Class` object exists for each reference type. It can be used, for example, to discover the fully qualified name of a class, its members, its immediate superclass, and any interfaces that it implements.
>
> The type of a method invocation expression of getClass is `Class<? extends |T|>` where `T` is the class or interface searched (§15.12.1) for getClass.

So the return type of getClass is the static (compile-time) type of the expression `getClass()` is invoked on. For instance:

```
String s = "";
Object o = s;
Class<? extends String> sc = s.getClass(); // ok
Class<? extends Object> oc = o.getClass(); // ok
oc = sc; // ok
sc = o.getClass(); // not ok
sc = oc; // not ok
```

The notation `|X|` is [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) in spec as follows:

> Type erasure is a mapping from types (possibly including parameterized types and type variables) to types (that are never parameterized types or type variables). We write `|T|` for the erasure of type `T`. The erasure mapping is defined as follows:
>
> - The erasure of a parameterized type (§4.5) `G<T1,...,Tn>` is `|G|`.
> - The erasure of a nested type `T.C` is `|T|.C`.
> - The erasure of an array type `T[]` is `|T|[]`.
> - The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.
> - The erasure of every other type is the type itself.

For instance, if we have:

```
List<String> list = ...;
```

the expression `list.getClass()` is of type `Class<? extends List>` rather than `Class<? extends List<String>>`.

Answer (score 8):

Let's consider the following example:

```
List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Class<? extends List> clazz = test.getClass();
```

the static type of `test` (`the expression on which getClass() is called`) is `List<Integer>` of which the erasure is `List` (see [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)). Note that the dynamic (or runtime) type of `test` is `ArrayList`, and the runtime type of `clazz` will be `Class<ArrayList>`.

So, `Class<? extends |X|>` in this case is `Class<? extends List>`.