# How to get Class<T> from List<T>

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I feel utterly silly for having to ask this, but I'm failing to understand why doesn't the following Java code compile:

```
void <T> doSomething(List<T> items) {
    Class<? extends T> clazz = items.get(0).getClass();
    ...
}
```

From Java doc:

> The actual result type is Class< ? extends |X|> where |X| is the
> erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is
> called. For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:
>
> Number n = 0;  Class< ? extends Number> c = n.getClass();

EDIT:

1. Found [this nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332856/what-is-meant-by-the-erasure-of-the-static-type-of-the-expression-on-which-it-i?rq=1) of what *erasure of the static type* means.
2. There's a way to preserve generic type information using subclasses, known as [super type token](http://gafter.blogspot.nl/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html?m=1). A now deleted answer helpfully pointed out that Guava library has a [convenient utility](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained) for exploiting this.
3. Here's a [great article](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/advanced-java-generics-retreiving-generic-type-arguments.html) on extracting generic types reflectively and a nice lib, called [GenTyRef](https://github.com/coekie/gentyref), simplifying it
4. I forked GenTyRef to add support for working with `AnnotatedType`s (introduced in Java 8). It's called [GeantyRef](https://github.com/leangen/geantyref) (and it's in Maven Central)

Comment: I think it is duplicate or at least matrix error, as i have a feeling i've seen this question earlier on SE

Comment: What if `T` is `List<String>`?  There is no `Class<List<String>>`.

Comment: You don't have `auto` in Java?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The erasure of the static type of `items.get(0)` is `Object` (since `T` is erased during compilation).

Therefore `items.get(0).getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends Object>`, not a `Class<? extends T>`, which explains why your attempted assignment fails.

This will pass compilation :

```
Class<? extends Object> clazz = items.get(0).getClass();
```

If you want the `Class` of the generic parameter to be known by that method, you can pass it as an additional argument.

```
void doSomething(List<T> items, Class<T> clazz) {

}
```

Comment: `Class<? extends Object>` is redundant, `Class<?>` is more concise

Comment: @user140547 I was following the language of the Javadoc (`Class<? extends |X|>`).

Comment: @Eran `Class<? extends T> clazz` isn't safe - you could call `doSomething(Arrays.<Number>asList(Double.valueOf(0)), Integer.class)`. You'd need to use `<? super T>`, no?

Comment: Hmm, this doesn’t explain *why* the result bears the “erasure of the static type of the expression” instead of just the “static type of the expression”…

Comment: @Holger: It's because `T` can represent non-reifiable types like `ArrayList<String>`. But class objects only represent reifiable types. There is only a `Class<ArrayList>`, not a `Class<ArrayList<String>>`.

Comment: @newacct: what kind of danger would implicitly representing `ArrayList.class` as a `Class<ArrayList<String>>` create? Keep in mind that we’re talking about code having only a `T [extends Object]` and a `Class<T>`, not even knowing that `T` is a `List` from the caller’s perspective…

Comment: @Holger: Well, for example you can use it to `.cast()` anything into `ArrayList<String>` without a unchecked warning (even though the type argument is not checked). Also, some things that ought to compile don't compile, like `List<Integer> a; List<String> b; if (a.getClass() == b.getClass()) ...`

Comment: @newacct: Now *that* should perhaps be included in the answer…

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to define T as type parameter for the method: `<T> void doSomething`. Then you need a cast to `Class<? extends T>`. So this is how you can put together:

```
<T> void doSomething(List<T> items) {
    Class<? extends T> clazz = (Class<? extends T>) items.get(0).getClass();
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is strange how erasure forces us to cast again.

Comment: The missing <T> was a typo. Casting will obviously work, but I needed an explanation as to why it was needed.