# How java determine where to insert the "type cast" in type erasure process

Tags: java, generics

Consider below code and the output in Eclipse 4.5.0 & javac(1.8) .

I know it is due to the type erasure in runtime, but why the second one still output data even it is declared as List of Integer, I also checked with javap, [checkcast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.checkcast) bytecode is only inserted in the third output .

My questions are :

1. is it a bug ?
2. How the javac determine where to insert the "cast" ?

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args){
   List<String> a = Arrays.asList("abc","def");
   List<Integer> b = (List<Integer>)(List<?>)a;
   System.out.println(b.size()); --output 2
   System.out.println(b.get(1)); ---output "def"
   System.out.println(b.get(1).getClass()); --error in type cast
   ```

**EDIT**

Checked the answer below and the [When is generic return value of function casted after type erasure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562435/when-is-generic-return-value-of-function-casted-after-type-erasure) , quite similar with my case.
If we add the answer from this [What is meant by "the erasure of the static type of the expression on which it is called" in the getClass() docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332856/what-is-meant-by-the-erasure-of-the-static-type-of-the-expression-on-which-it-i/19333305#19333305), then it will be much clear about the "cast" rule.

The compiler can determine where to insert the cast and ensure type safety.

My first case is fine since it will return int anyway.

Second case is fine since the println expect Object. so no cast is needed to ensure type safety.

Thrid case is not since the getClass() is expected to return the Class which is the static type of b.get(1) according to JLS. So the cast is inserted and get type cast error.

As @newacct said , "you should not rely on the compiler to decide either way" (when there is alternative choice and also ensure type safety ,the 2nd case here).

Comment: #2 works because of type erasure. It no longer cares that you "lied" about it being an Integer as it's forgotten about it being anything other than an Object. I don't know why #3 fails.

Comment: @Novaterata, i do not think so . erasure is not simply remove the parameter variable , but also insert "necessary cast ". Thus the third one has a cast inserted , so it will be  ((Integer)b.get(1)).getClass() which will fail in type checking at runtime.

Comment: #2 and #3 were referring to the print statements

Comment: a and b is definitely a List of plain Object at runtime

Comment: The key word is "necessary" cast. Those print methods are for Object so no cast is necessary

Comment: Aha, I see your point. You mean since the argument for println is Object, so no cast is necessary for the 2nd one, right ? I thought as that in the first place as well . But what i think is  : java should add cast in all places except those one which could be left out and also keep type safety. So i could understand 3rd one is wrong , but do not understand why 2nd works

Comment: . toString() is a method in Object. All objects have hashCode toString equals etc. Therefore they can all be printed

Comment: But they also have getClass. I honestly don't know why #3 fails

Answer (score 0):

In the last example, the cast happens as follows

```
Class clazz = ((Integer)b.get(1)).getClass();
```

And hence the exception, where the second line

```
System.out.println(b.get(1));
```

Does not assign to an integer and hence the cast wont happen, assign it to an integer to see it failing.

```
Integer x = b.get(1); //fails
```

Comment: then why the 2nd succeed ?

Comment: @Keith check the edit

Comment: You don't need to cast to `Integer` to call `getClass`, since it is a method of `Object`. So why is there a cast in the third case?

Comment: @JornVernee I guess it's simply easier to always cast to `Integer` when a method is called.